# Aligning 3 divs with outer 2 stretching 100% in either direction?

Tags: css, html, alignment

Im wanting to align 3 divs together, but i want the left div to stretch 100% left, the right 100% right with the middle div having a fixed width.

Basically I'm trying to create a header for my website with the logo in the middle and the background seemingly stretching out forever but the logo has transparency so I can't just overlay one ontop of the other.

I have done this using tabels at the moment like below but wondered if there was a better (css) way of doing it?

The Real issue being that the background of the logo in the center of the banner needs to be transparent so i cant have any overlapping divs?

Here is my example done using the following method but would prefer to use CSS if possible?

LINK: [example](http://www.aniworld.plus.com/2013)

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <th scope="col" style="width:50%; height:123px; background-image:url(style/images/header_bckdrp.png); background-repeat:repeat-x"></th>
    <th scope="col"><img src="style/images/header_logo.png" width="122" height="123" alt="Header_logo"></th>
    <th scope="col" style="width:50%; height:123px; background-image:url(style/images/header_bckdrp.png); background-repeat:repeat-x"></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: maybe something like what I've done here?[link](http://www.domscodestage.com/LPAC%20site/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<style type="text/css>

#left, #right{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
width:50%;
height:50px;
}

#left, #headerpattern_left, #rightsticky{
left:0px;
}

#right, #headerpattern_right, #leftsticky,{
right:0px;
}

#headerpattern_left, #headerpattern_right{
position:absolute;
background:url(pattern.png) repeat-x;
width:45%;
}

#leftsticky, #rightsticky{
    position:absolute;
}

#logo{
position:relative;
width:50px;
height:50px;
margin:0px auto;
}

</style>

<body>

<div>
    <div id="left">
        <div id="headerpattern_left">
        </div>
        <div id="leftsticky>
            <img src="correctly_measured_image_of_pattern_on_left_side_of_logo.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="headerpattern_right">
        </div>
        <div id="rightsticky>
            <img src="correctly_measured_image_of_pattern_on_right_side_of_logo.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

EDIT: new suggestion

Off the top of my head, you could create two divs within each of the left and right divs and create a jpeg of how the pattern should look 100px either side of the logo and have them stick right next to the logo, then use the same repeating background on the divs next to the jpegs.

This should work in most cases, but in a few instances it will not look perfect, such as if the webpage is viewed on a gigantic screen or zoomed out quite far. Also, I'm not sure how it will look on mobile devices.

Comment: This is good thanks but the issue im still having is that the center logo image needs/wants to be transparent in places, this wont work with this set up as the left and right are underlapping the logo image? here is an example using the abvoe table method: http://www.aniworld.plus.com/2013/  thanx for all your help so far! as you can tell im still learning and am not too sure what can and cant be done?? :)

Comment: @user1951775 I have updated the code with a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this method will work for what you are trying to achieve, but you can horizontaly center the image and then apply a background color, so it will cover the background image. You shouldn't be using empty elements, they are semantically incorrect. It's up to you though.

Take a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/BwJIv).

Comment: Semantically incorrect but sometimes necessary for whatever reason, without more context it's impossible to judge although I suspect there is a far easier way to achieve whatever it is he/she wants.